# How to display Model property name instead of Json key names in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model interface Employee defined:

```
export interface Employee {
   Name: string;
   Joining:string;
   Team: string;
   Manager: string;
   Position: string;
   Rating: string;
}
```

I get the values from a service by calling an Api in the following format:

```
{
  employee_name: "James", joining_year: "2004", employee_rating: "", job_position: "Network Staff Member", manager_name: "Joel", team_name: "Network"
}
```

I want to display the Property name of models instead of the Json key names.
Currently it is displayed like this:

```
employee_name    joining_year  manager_name
   James              2004           Joel
```

I want to show it like:

```
Name               Joining          Manager  
James                2004              Joel
```

I am getting the json response this way:

```
this._employeeService.getData()
  .subscribe(response => {
        this.empInfo = <Employee>response;
   });
```

Something I tried:

Getting the data for columns:

```
 Object.keys(this.empInfo[0]).forEach((item: string) => {
    this.columns.push({ title: item});
});
```

Template code:

```
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
  <div class='panel-heading'>
    {{pageTitle}}
  </div>
  <div class='panel-body'>
    <div class='table-responsive'>
      <table class='table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th *ngFor="let column of columns">
                  {{column.title}}
                </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor='let employee of empInfo'>
            <td>{{ employee?.employee_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee?.joining_year }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee?.manager_name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to make an intermediate contract or something similar. Besides, remember that interfaces, in typescript, **does not exist at all at runtime**, hence you probably would like to use a **class** instead. What I can suggest you, if your are acquiring the response from the rest api, is to use the library **cerialize** https://github.com/weichx/cerialize .This would be by far the most reliable solution (use `@autoserializeAs` to accomplish your goal)

Comment: How do you show the data on the template? Can you include the code?

Comment: Added template code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map your data inside the getData method:

```
this._employeeService.getData()
  .subscribe(response => {
      this.empInfo = response.map(
      employee => {
        return {
          Name: employee.employee_name,
          Joining: employee.joining_year,
          Rating: employee.employee_rating,
          Position: employee.job_position,
          Manager: employee.manager_name,
          Team: employee.team_name
        }
      }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your data to your class by `map`

So , in your `getData()`

```
getData() {
  return this._http.get('url')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json().map(res => new Employee(res.employee_name, res.joining_year, manager_name)));
  }
```

and your class has a constructor

```
public interface IEmployee 
{
   Name: string;
   Joining:string;
   Team: string;
   Manager: string;
   Position: string;
   Rating: string;
}

public class Employee extends IEmployee {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public year: string,
        public manager: string
      ) 
    {
          //set properties....
    }
}
```